# Setting up Virtual Environment for Django in python

Tags: python, django, virtual, python-venv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVkmp.png) please help

python3 -m venv venv

Comment: You will need to add more context of the problem, what you are trying to achieve, what have you try so far, etc. Take a look to the guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In the main directory root add the following command to create the environment:

`$ python3 -m venv venv` this code will create a folder called venv in the root. Which basically is the virtual environment folder.

Then add the following command to activate the virtual environment:

`$ source venv/bin/activate`

```
your_project_folder/
 |
 |-- your_main_app_folder/
 |         |
 |         |--Folder_with_controllers/
 |         |            settings.py
 |         |            urls.py
 |         |            ...
 |         | 
 |         |--App_folder/
 |         |--Other_app_folder/
 |
 |--venv/
```

If the code works fine your bash should look like this: `(venv) <the_path_for_the_folder> your_project_folder`

After activated your environment you can now install django and other packages.

Ps: make sure you instal and activate the virtual environment folder not in the your_main_app_folder.